# Как встроить рисунок matplotlib в интерфейс?

Tags: python, matplotlib, интерфейс, pysimplegui

Я создаю интерфейс при помощи Pysimplegui.

Вот его часть

```
layout = [[sg.Frame('', [[sg.Text('Выберите растровый файл', size=(24, 1), font=('Courier 10', 12)),
                      sg.InputText(key="raster_file_path", size=(47, 1)),
                      sg.FileBrowse('Обзор', file_types=[("Tiff Files", "*.tif")])],
                     [sg.Text('Границы интервалов', size=(24, 1), font=('Courier 10', 12)),
                      sg.InputText(key="interval", size=(14, 1), enable_events=True, justification='right'),
                      sg.Button('Добавить', bind_return_key=True, font=('Courier 10', 9), size=(18, 1)),
                      sg.Button('Удалить', bind_return_key=True, font=('Courier 10', 9), size=(18, 1))],
                     [sg.Table(values=[], headings=["Значение"], auto_size_columns=True, justification='right', key="table", expand_x=True)],
                     [sg.Button('Классифицировать', bind_return_key=True, font=('Courier 10', 14), size=(27, 1), key='clas_v'),
                      sg.Button('Векторизовать', bind_return_key=True, font=('Courier 10', 14), size=(27, 1), key='vector_v')],
                     [sg.Output(size=(1, 10), font='Courier 10', expand_x=True)]]),
       sg.Column([[sg.Frame('', [[sg.Text('')], [sg.Canvas(key='-CANVAS-', size=(600, 390))]])],
                  [sg.Button('Обновить', bind_return_key=True, expand_x=True, font=('Courier 10', 14))]])]]

window = sg.Window("Классификация", layout, resizable=True)
figure_agg = None

def classify(raster, interval):
    with rasterio.open(raster) as src:
        image = src.read(1)

    classified_image = np.digitize(image, interval, right=True)

    ris, ax = plt.subplots()

    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet', len(interval) - 1)
    im = ax.imshow(classified_image, cmap=cmap, vmin=1, vmax=len(interval) - 1)
    plt.colorbar(im, ax=ax, ticks=range(1, len(interval) + 1))

    fig = plt.gcf()

    return fig, classified_image

intervals = []

while True:
    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break

    if event == 'clas_v':
        raster = values['raster_file_path']
        class_image = k_means(raster, intervals)

        figure_agg = draw_figure(window['-CANVAS-'].TKCanvas, class_image[0])
```

После вызова функции рисунок добавляется в '-CANVAS-', но не так, как это выглядит, если вызвать просто функцию plt.show(). Не добавляются элементы из левого нижнего угла ("Reset original view", "Zoom to rectangle"), а также, когда водишь курсором по рисунку в правом нижнем углу не отображаются координаты пикселя и его значения. Как добавить эти элементы в данном случае?

Comment: https://github.com/PySimpleGUI/PySimpleGUI/blob/master/DemoPrograms/Demo_Matplotlib_Embedded_Toolbar.py